# ScalaMock, returns based on a ClassTag

Tags: scala, testing, stub, stubbing, scalamock

How can I stub a method that use a `ClassTag` in the implementation ?

```
class RefsFactory {
  def get[I <: Item : ClassTag]: RefTo[I] = {
    val itemType = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
    // ...
  }
}
```

This class is used a lot in our code and I would like to stub it to return others mock regarding the `itemType`.

```
val factory = stub[RefsFactory]
val otherType = stub[RefTo[OtherType]]
(factory.get[OneType]) returns RefTo(new OneType())
(factory.get[OtherType]) returns otherType
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to simplify your problem, the method

```
def get[I <: Item : ClassTag]: RefTo[I]
```

is similar to having a context bound on 0-arity method

```
def foo[I: ClassTag]
```

which is equivalent to method with one implicit argument

```
def foo[I](implicit ev: ClassTag[I)
```

hence considering [Methods with implicit parameters](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/#example-4---methods-with-implicit-parameters) we can mock like so

```
(myMock.foo[SomeType](_: ClassTag[SomeType])).expects(*).returns(...)
```